# Show that something is not a sub-manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm in a multivariable calculus course and I quite struggle with proofs where to show that something is not a sub-manifold. As you can't use the pre-image theorem, can someone please explain a relative solid "method" to start such a proof. 
For example for this sub-manifold M ={(x,y)∈ R^2 |xy=0}

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This sort of question has been answered many times here. See, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244116/proving-a-subset-is-not-a-submanifold/2244167#comment4618286_2244167) or  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357697/is-m-x-y-in-bbbr2-x2-y5-a-differentiable-submanifold/1357857#1357857). In general, you should search the site a bit before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider the set $M = \{(x,y): xy = 0\}$ then we observe that it is just the union of the sets $\{(x,0)\} \cup \{(0,y)\}$ i.e we can embed $M$ so that $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the union of the coordinate lines $(0,t,0)$ and $(s,0,0)$.

Observe that $M$ cannot be a $1$-manifold since it is non-compact and would have to homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ which we see is not true. If you think $M$ is a surface, take an open ball $B$ about $(0,0)$ and consider $B \cap M$. No matter how small the ball is, this intersection looks like an $\textbf{X}$ which is not homeomorphic to a disk.

Comment: This is not a proof of anything. And why did you put things in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: What do you mean, this isn't the proof of anything? This proves the statement, anything else if just fancy. A question of rigor maybe, but to say it proves nothing, I don't agree. Also, I put things in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since the OP said sub-manifold i.e subset of some other manifold. The canonical choice in this case is $\mathbb{R}^3$.