# Proving this subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to show that the set $$X = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^{2}=y^{3}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} $$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I understand that the curve isn't smooth at $(0,0)$ and this is why, but I just can't translate this into a proper proof. I know it has to do with the implicit function theorem (or inverse function theorem?) but I'm not sure how those theorems help here. The explanations for similar examples that I have seen make use of these tools but they are a little hand-wavey and I just don't see how to formalise the argument.

Comment: $X$ is the union of two curves, the graph of $x = y^{3/2}$ and the graph of $x = -y^{3/2}$.  These intersect at one point, the origin.  So in any $\Bbb{R}^2$-neighborhood of the origin, the intersection of $X$ with that neighborhood is isotopic to "X", that is, two intersecting line segments...

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357697/is-m-x-y-in-bbbr2-x2-y5-a-differentiable-submanifold/1357857#1357857).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your reply. I have seen this but I don't understand how we can show the inverse function theorem implies that locally any submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a smooth function. I've been re-reading through the statements of the theorem and definition of submanifold but i just dont see it.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't understand the last bit - the intersection of $X$ with that neighbourhood is isotopic to $X$? What does isotopic mean here? What's the issue with a neighbourhood of the origin giving two intersecting line segments? If we take out a point the result is still homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, no?

Comment: The tangent line to the submanifold at any given point must project isomorphically to (at least) one of the coordinate axes.

Comment: @TedShifrin I haven't learnt about tangents to manifolds yet :/

Comment: 'the intersection of X with that neighborhood is isotopic to "X", that is, two intersecting line segments'...  "X" is not $X$.  "X" is a letter made by two linear strokes.  The issue is that we either get a neighborhood of $\Bbb{R}$ or a neighborhood of $\Bbb{R}^2$ if this is a submanifold -- so which is is?  If we take out a point, it isn't even connected, so cannot be homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let suppose that $X$ is a manifold, then locally in $(0,0)$ the set $X$ is the graph of a differentiable function $g$, which satisfies $g(0)=0$. Then $x^3=g(x)^2$. If $n$ is the order of $g$ at $0$ then $2n=3$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why must the set $X$ locally be the graph of a differentiable function? I don't see why this follows from the definition of a submanifold/inverse function thm. Also, what does the 'order' of g mean?

Comment: I suggest this document for you (Proposition 3.2.1) https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/andrews/DG/DG_chap3.pdf